# Handle multiple asynchronous post request in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

Here is a situation .. we have a UI where you select the products you want to install on the vm, so initially we used to send the payload with array of JavaScript object where each object holds information about the product. once installation of all products is done then we used to receive the response. but now we are changing the process. first you select all products which you want to install on the VM and once you start the installation then one by one product is installed and you can see live status on the UI like which product is in progress and whose installation is completed and what all is remaining.

In technical language .. using angular service we used to send array of objects where on success of all products installation we used to get the response, but incase of failure of any one it was difficult to track what all installation completed and which are remaining. So in order to simplify this process we have decided that one by one we will send the product for installation and corresponding success/failue status we will show on the screen. the challenge i am facing is that how i can make asynchronous call for each object present in the array one after another.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I tried a for loop in services but it seems not working only one product is being installed .. actually not able to handle promise properly.

Comment: show us your code, then only we could help

Answer (score 0):

You could try looping over an array of product infos, and call the install product function on success every time:

```
var arrayOfProducts = [
  {..},
  {..}
];

function installProduct(product) {
  if(!product) {
    return;
  }

  var request = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: '..',
    data: product
  };

  return $http(request)
    .then(function() {
      var nextProduct = arrayOfProducts.shift();
      return installProduct(nextProduct);
    });
}

var firstProduct = arrayOfProducts.shift();
installProduct(firstProduct);
```

This code is untestes, but it should only be an idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try to use recursion with a flag like that:

assume that myArray is array of datas.

```
var myflag = 0;

function myFunction(){

 if(myFlag <= myArray.length -1){

   var dataToSend = myArray[myFlag];

     $http.post('URL', dataToSend).then(
       function success(response){
        myFlag++;
        myFunction();
       }
     );

   }

}
```